# what is the proper xml syntax for defining <multicheckbox> form element in zend form

Tags: xml, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm creating Zend_Form using Xml config which defines two element select and multicheckbox. I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876344/what-is-the-proper-syntax-for-describing-a-select-form-element-to-zend-form-usi) which has answered one my of question however I cannot find any example of multicheckbox element syntax.

any help is appreciated.

here is what i have done so far (for fun)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
    <localhost>
        <formmanager>
            <pizza>
                <action>/form/</action>
                <method>post</method>
                <name>Pizza</name>
                <elements>
                    <crust>
                        <type>Select</type>
                        <name>crust</name>

                        <options>
                            <label>Crust:</label>
                            <required>true</required>
                            <multioptions>
                                <option value="Thin crust">Thin crust</option>
                                <option value="Thick crust">Thick crust</option>
                            </multioptions>
                        </options>
                    </crust>
                    <pan>
                        <type>MultiCheckbox</type>
                        <required>true</required>
                        <options>
                            <label>Pan:</label>
                            <multioptions>
                                <option>American Hot</option>
                                <option>Cheese and tomato</option>
                            </multioptions>
                        </options>
                    </pan>
                </elements>
            </pizza>
        </formmanager>
    </localhost>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** After a long time, looking through Zend_Config, Zend_Config_Xml, Zend_Form_Element_MultiChoiceBox and Zend_Form_Element_Multi class, I figured it out and here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
    <localhost>
        <formmanager>
            <pizza>
                <action>/form/</action>         
                <method>post</method>           
                <name>Pizza</name>              
                <elements>
                    <crust>
                        <type>Select</type>             
                        <name>crust</name>              
                        <options>                       
                            <label>Crust:</label>           
                            <required>true</required>       
                            <multioptions>                  
                                <thin_crust>Thin Crust</thin_crust>
                                <thick_crust>Thick Crust</thick_crust>
                            </multioptions>                 
                            <value>test</value>             
                        </options>                      
                    </crust>
                    <pan>
                        <type>MultiCheckbox</type>      
                        <name>pan</name>                
                        <options>                       
                            <label>Pan:</label>             
                            <multioptions>                  
                                <american>American Hot</american>
                                <cheese>Cheese and Tomato</cheese>
                            </multioptions>                 
                            <required>true</required>       
                        </options>                      
                    </pan>
                </elements>
            </pizza>
        </formmanager>
    </localhost>
</form>
```